# Firestore does not work seem to work offline

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to create a Progressive web app with firestore. The web app works correctly when the computer is online but doesn't work when offline.

I have enabled firestore offline persistence like below-

```
firebase.firestore().settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true });
firebase.firestore().enablePersistence().then(() => {
    this.db = firebase.firestore();
});
```

I am getting the following error if I run the app when the computer is offline.

```
[2018-10-23T07:15:24.406Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (5.5.0): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=unavailable]: The operation could not be completed
This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
```

Trying to get a document from the firestore database fails with error

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Failed to get document because the client is offline.
```

I understand that both of these errors are technically correct. But shouldn't these errors not occur because I have enabled offline persistence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Get offline data:** If you get a document while the device is offline,
>   Cloud Firestore returns data from the cache. If the cache does not
>   contain data for that document, or the document does not exist, the
>   get call returns an error.
>
> **Query offline data:** Querying works with offline persistence. You can
>   retrieve the results of queries with either a direct get or by
>   listening, as described in the preceding sections. You can also create
>   new queries on locally persisted data while the device is offline, but
>   the queries will initially run only against the cached documents.

Offline persistence doesn´t mean that your Client can communicate with Firestore while having no internet, it means that for example Changes he makes get submitted to the relevant Document once a internet connection occurs again.

Think about caching relevant Files for the User to use the PWA Offline to a certain extend.

[More info about using it Offline](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline)